# What happens if I have same duplicate UUID in report?

Tags: jasper-reports, uuid

In my jasper report, I am using elements something like this:

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
    <reportElement style="alternateStyle" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="292" y="0" width="85" height="30" uuid="b93b4e99-d6fb-4679-836d-9b198cb5fe1c"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
        <font fontName="SMCustomFont" size="9" isBold="false"/>
        <paragraph leftIndent="3"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{SOMEEXP}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Here the uuid is "b93b4e99-d6fb-4679-836d-9b198cb5fe1c".

My question is What happens if I keep the UUID same for some other textField element in the same JRXML file and what is the significance of UUID?

When I tried, the report is generating fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jasper reports use the `UUID` in the engine to identify elements, see for example [`SortElementJsonHandler.getCurrentSortField`](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/blob/master/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/components/sort/SortElementJsonHandler.java#L189).

A Friendly User (staff) at the Jasper Community forum [states](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/1117541/which-goal-uuid-attribute-jasper-elements)

> UUID is used mostly for the interactive elements like tables and crosstabs to identify the elements for sorting/filtering/etc. It's used in the viewer and on the engine level, I am not sure there is useful API available to interact with elements using UUID.

Also as far as I can [see](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/search?l=Java&q=uuid), in most simple cases like two `textField` there is no problem having same `UUID`, but you can get strange result if you have a more complex design with multiple similar components and all of them have same `UUID`

### Use the IDE and you don't need to worry about it.

If you copy and past elements/components in the raw jrxml, either change a number or remove the `UUID`, when saved in JasperSoft Studio it will auto-generate it for you if it does not exists. Overall I would suggest that you use the IDE for all actions (copy and past etc), personally I only use the code/jrxml view if I need to do some quick replace of something etc.